# WordPress: External call to wp-load.php causes CPU and memory spikes

Tags: wordpress, memory, cpu

One of my websites on my server is causing big CPU and memory spikes. I've been looking for the cause, and I believe that I've found it.

I've been digging in the access logs and every time a peak occurs, there is an external call to wp-load.php. This call looks like this (I've changed a few values):

```
52.56.220.94 - - [16/Oct/2018:12:57:20 +0200] "POST /wp-load.php?pubkey=c924c49878aec6f8295874888c0d14c1&bvTime=1539687440&bvVersion=0.1&bvMethod=getdata&sha1=true&sig=6d3a8735567bd7baa7e5e12af885afab0d6a399d HTTP/1.0" 200 4809 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
```

The calls come from a limited range of IP-addresses:

52.56.220.94

54.179.150.144

45.77.97.238

Does anyone recognize this and/or does anyone know a way to track down to which piece of software this call belongs to?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: An "external call to wp-load.php" sounds very fishy to me. Are these IP addresses on your subnet? I can't think of any "good" reason to call wp-load.php from an external server ....

Comment: It's apparently from a plugin called Malcare. See these links:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/deleted-malcare-security-plugin-but-still-having-problems/
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/strange-links-inside-live-traffic-tab-i-need-your-opinion/ Plugin support staff there said "We try to ping your site once a day to check if the plugin is present and if it is then we then try to scan your site. That is why you’re seeing the requests in the log." My opinion is that once a plugin is uninstalled ​it shouldn't try to scan your site at all but I guess that's how Malcare does things.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
<Files "wp-load.php">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

I can't think of a reason to bootstrap WordPress from an external server ....

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I've added this to my .htaccess. Let's see what happens. :-)